# Python: SGDClassifier for X without feature names

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm following the examples in the book: Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow, 2nd Edition.

In chapter 3, the example get mnist_784 dataset via fetch_openml while I got the data set via download the .csv file from kaggle.

The code in the book:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_openml
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

mnist = fetch_openml('mnist_784', version=1)
X, y = mnist["data"], mnist["target"]
some_digit = X[0]
some_digit_image = some_digit.reshape(28, 28)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X[:60000], X[60000:], y[:60000], y[60000:]
y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)  # True for all 5s, False for all other digits
y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)
```

The openml dataset includes the description, data and target but unfortunately the .csv file doesn't have the same information.

And my code is:

```
file = r"C:\data\cwd\Jupyter\data\mnist_784.csv"
mnist = pd.read_csv(file)
X = mnist.loc[:, mnist.columns != 'class']
y = mnist.loc[:, 'class']
some_digit = X.iloc[0].tolist()
some_digit_image = np.reshape(some_digit,(28, 28))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X.iloc[:60000], X.iloc[60000:], y.iloc[:60000], y.iloc[60000:]
y_train_5 = (y_train == 5)
y_test_5 = (y_test == 5)
sgd_clf = SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train, y_train_5)
```

So far all good.
However, when I ran below:

```
sgd_clf.predict([some_digit])
```

I got an warning message:

```
c:\data\tools\Python\sklearn\base.py:445: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but SGDClassifier was fitted with feature names
```

Can I supress the message, or can I attach the feature names to my X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just run into this warning too. I find the problem is because X is a dataframe. If you convert to a numpy array before training, this resolves the problem.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

X_train_ar=X_train.to_numpy()
some_digit=X_train_ar[0]
sgd_clf=SGDClassifier(random_state=42)
sgd_clf.fit(X_train_ar,y_train_5)
sgd_clf.predict([some_digit])
```